# According to Nyaya, are Mahabharata and Ramayan real or mythology?

Tags: history, nyaya, ramayana

According to Nyaya school of philosophy in Hinduism, is itihaas like Ramayan and Mahabharata real history or mythology .

Comment: How it is opinion based

Comment: It is not even remotely opinion-based - but it is a question some HSE members might find offensive to their belief-system @darkknight

Comment: Is this real? May be I can say that those stories were as real (or as unreal as me and you) #Advaitha vedanta